# Finding the Polarity of particular word using sentiWordNet

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working on Opinion Mining Algorithm in which,  I am trying to find the polarity of the particular word.

Algorithm states - Search for any other POS categories like Noun, Adjective, Adverb and accumulate their polarity values using SentiWordNet.

I integrated the SentiWordNet in my current system and its working perfectly for determining the polarity of the sentence. But I want a polarity for particular word.

I found one method senti_classifier.synsets_score() which seem to be useful but I am unable to find any documentation related to this.

Can anyone describe the usage of above method or guide me to the documentation site.?
Is there any other way by which I can find the polarity of a particular word?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [example code by Petter Törnberg provided on the SentiWordNet site](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/code/SentiWordNetDemoCode.java). It calculates the sentiment score of each word in the thesaurus as a weighted average of the scores of its synsets.

Comment: Is there any python equivalent for this Java code. I missed to mention that I am using Python.

Comment: In Python, you can use NLTK's SentiWordNet interface to achieve the same goal: http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for. hanks.!!

Comment: Despite it is reported that SentiWordNet calculates polarity scores in the `[0, 1]` range; this sample code calculates negative polarity scores too. Any ideas about that? @yvespeirsman